# Como criar redirecionamentos por país?

Tags: php, javascript, html, redirecionamento

Como posso fazer para criar redirecionamentos por país?

Digo, vamos supor que eu receba um visitante do *México*, então teria que redirecionar para `meusite.com/mx/`, já se eu receber uma visita do *Brasil* vá para `meusite.com/br/` ou até mesmo se receber uma visita de *Portugal* redirecione para `meusite.com/pt/`, etc...

Como posso fazer isso? Qual a melhor solução?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar alguns recursos.

### Quando o browser tem acesso a geolocalização

Você pode usar javascript para obter a geolocalização do request. Porém, você vai ter que saber que longitude A e latitude B, faz parte do país X. Acredito que isso vai lhe gerar um certo trabalho:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var la = position.coords.latitude;
            var lo = position.coords.longitude; console.log([la, lo]);
        });
    }
```

### Basear-se no ip que fez o request

Existem empresas que lhe dão o local exato do request baseado no ip, por exemplo, a empresa: https://www.maxmind.com/

### Entregar o que o usuário quer ver (como o pessoal faz geralmente)

Uma das formas de se identificar qual linguagem o usuário **quer** receber o conteúdo do post (o response) é avaliando a variável `Accept-Language` que vem no request.

Por exemplo, em php seria:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']; 
// "en-US,en;q=0.8"
```

Nesse caso, o usuário aceita (deseja) receber o conteúdo em `en-US`. Assim, você sabe exatamente para onde redirecionar um post que vem de `meusite.com/` para `meusite.com/en` por exemplo.

Essa é a forma mais comum de se identificar "de onde vem" o usuário, porque o usuário geralmente configura o que ele quer receber de acordo com o lugar que eles está: se está no Estados Unidos - en-US, se está no Brasil - pt-BR. Porém, essa não é um regra. Alguns usuários podem configurar os seus browsers `en-US`, estar no Brasil e ignorar todas as outras linguagens. Então, essa forma de identificar o idioma não é baseada de onde o usuário está, mas sim do que o usuário quer receber - o que é muito melhor no meu entendimento.

Caso o usuário seja japones e esteja no Brasil, o ideal é redirecioná-lo para `meusite.com/jp`, considerando que esse usuário estará mais confortável com o idioma nativo dele.

### Para redirecionar em PHP

```
$lang = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
header("Location: http://www.meusite.com/$lang" ) ;
```

Comment: Alexandre o `en` significa "eu prefiro inglês", o `en-US` significa eu aceito qualquer língua inglêsa do Estados unidos e o `q=0.8` é chamado de fator de qualidade relativa (relative quality factor), e representa a estimativa da preferência do usuário. Mais detalhes em: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4

Comment: Primeiro: você não sabe expressar muito bem o que você quer. Já viu quantas perguntas tem dentro de sua pergunta? Cada ponto de interrogação é um pergunta. Segundo: não estou aqui para te ensinar nada. Toda resposta é um auxílio. Não sou seu professor! Você deveria prestar mais atenção nos comentários que faz e tentar evitar ser menos rude com quem tenta lhe ajudar com um problema.

Comment: A resposta é ótima, @AlexandreLopes; super completa, obrigado Maia! Se o que queres é só copy/paste, então a opção de comprar um script foi muito acertada.

Comment: Agora sim! Muito obrigado!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Ficou melhor que o script! :D

Comment: Sim. O código final está com problema. Eu coloquei aspas simples e deveria ser aspas duplas para concatenar a variável $lang com a string. Corrigido.

Comment: Agora foi para `meusite.com/pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4` deveria ser só até a primeira vírgula.

Comment: Então é só você tratar a string $lang e obter apenas a parte que você deseja. Por exemplo: `$lang = split(",", $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])[0];`

Comment: Esse código acima está errado. Você é um Gênio!!!! e se eu quiser só o que tem dentro da segunda vírgula, no caso: `pt` ? Desculpe pelo tanto de perguntas. :3

Comment: Utilize o próximo índice. No caso, troque o índice `[0]` para `[1]`. Se você não sabe tratar string e manipular array`s, sugiro que dê uma olhada em: http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.strings.php e http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.array.php. Vai lhe ajudar a entender melhor o php.

Comment: Mais o código tá errado, no DreamWeaver diz que está errado, e quando abro no navegador fica só uma tela branca.

Comment: Essa parte que está errada: `$lang = split(",", $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])[0];`