# Como re-criar uma URL com Accept-Language + split ?

Tags: php

Estou com um código em `PHP` [criado pelo membro @Maia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22861/como-criar-redirecionamentos-por-pa%C3%ADs), ele informa o idioma do navegador e retorna com um **redirecionamento**.

*Código*

```
<?php
$lang = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
header("Location: http://meusite.com/$lang" ) ;
?>
```

Ele redireciona para:

```
meusite.com/pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

O certo seria ele redirecionar para `meusite.com/pt-BR` porque o meu navegador está com o idioma `pt-BR`.

Será que criando um `split` resolveria?

---

O membro @Maia fez assim:

```
$lang = split(",", $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])[0];
```

No caso a URL iria só até a primeira vírgula, deixando assim só: `meusite.com/pt-BR`.
Só que o código parece estar errado, não funciona.

Gostaria de fazer isso com a URL, deixando até `/pt-BR`, ou até mesmo deixá-lo:

```
meusite.com/pt
```

O membro sugeriu que eu trocasse o índice de [0] para [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22861/como-criar-redirecionamentos-por-pa%C3%ADs) deixando assim:

```
$lang = split(",", $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])[1];
```

Só que não funciona, então gostaria de algum exemplo de como fazer com que redirecione para ***/pt-BR*** ou como redirecionar para ***/pt***

Comment: É o clássico [ProblemaXY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1202/70). Na minha humilde opinião, a [pergunta original](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22861/) era muito melhor, mas me parece que você deu accept na primeira resposta, que apesar de boa talvez não tenha resolvido inteiramente seu problema.

Comment: @Bacco
Como posso resolver isso? Ajuda-me novamente man! rs

Comment: Ela resolve, agora minha dúvida é só como mudar a URL. #Simplesmente

Comment: No momento não posso te ajudar, pq estou resolvendo outras coisas, mas vamos torcer pra alguém dar mais alternativas naquela questão, pois há vários meios pra se lidar com isso. Até servidores como o Apache já tem essa funcionalidade internamente, pode notar que a instalação padrão (a página de bem vindo do apache) atende a linguagem do sew browser automaticamente, mesmo sem PHP: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html

Comment: Sempre que eu peço ajuda a você, você diz que está ocupado... Típico. rsrsrs Mais não tem problema! ;)

Comment: Segue uma solução sem muita otimização, só pra vc parar de mimimi :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue uma *solução rápida* <sup>1</sup>:

```
<?php

$langs = array();
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {

   // Cá entre nós, usar regex pra isso é forçar a amizade, mas lá vai :)
   preg_match_all('/([a-z]{1,8}(-[a-z]{1,8})?)\s*(;\s*q\s*=\s*(1|0\.[0-9]+))?/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], $lang_parse);

   //Aqui vamos ordenar por preferência do usuário
   if (count($lang_parse[1])) {
      $langs = array_combine($lang_parse[1], $lang_parse[4]);
      foreach ($langs as $lang => $val) {
         if ($val === '') $langs[$lang] = 1;
      }
      arsort($langs, SORT_NUMERIC);
   }
}

// Aqui você põe apenas as linguagens que seu site REALMENTE tem:
foreach ($langs as $lang => $val) {
   if ( strpos($lang, 'pt') === 0) {
      header( "Location: http://meusite.com/pt/" ) ;
      exit();
   } else if (strpos($lang, 'en') === 0) {
      header( "Location: http://meusite.com/en/" ) ;
      exit();
   } 
}
// Se nao achar nenhuma:
header( "Location: http://meusite.com/pt/" ) ;
exit();

?>
```

Não precisa por `pt-BR`, nem `en-US`, a não ser que queira separar por exemplo o `pt-BR` do `pt-PT`, e assim por diante.

<sub>1. pesquisada no Duck Duck Go, correndo.</sub>

<sub>Fonte:http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-accept-language-header</sub>

Comment: Agradeça ao autor original e ao http://ddg.gg

Comment: Isso é muito top! É muito melhor do que redirecionamento por IP.

Comment: Essa solução (assim como a do apache que eu comentei) é boa por respeitar a vontade do usuário. Só pq um brasileiro viaja pros EUA nao quer dizer que ele vá ler sites em ingles, por exemplo (o que aconteceria se fosse mudar a lingua por IP ou geolocalização). Geolocalização é bom se o cara for procurar um restaurante perto, ou coisa do tipo. E IP é bom pra estatisticas suas, e nao pro usuário final.

Comment: Qual você acha melhor, por IP ou por Idioma ? Pelo Idioma é bom pelo fato de respeitar a vontade do usuário, só que e se o navegador estiver com linguagem `en`? como o seu Iron. Já por IP ele não respeitará a vontade do usuário. Estou em dúvida. E você? Por Idioma pode ser melhor? Diz aí! :D

Comment: @AlexandreLopes o meu Iron tá em en pq eu deixei em en, se quiser é só mudar nas configs tambem. É que meu windows está em ingles tambem, entao ficou com a linguagem padrão do sistema.